# No plugin found for prefix 'DarchetypeRepository=https' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, maven

I'm trying to generate a new Java project using Oracle maven dependencies.

I did the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.oracle.weblogic.archetype
-DarchetypeArtifactId=basicWebapp
-DarchetypeVersion=12.1.3-0-0
-DarchetypeRepository=https://maven.oracle.com
```

And got the following error:

```
Downloading: https://maven.oracle.com/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://maven.oracle.com/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 9.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 14.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.036 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-16T19:20:10+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/151M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'DarchetypeRepository=https' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo
] available from the repositories [local (C:\maven2\repo), 
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Note: I have my POM and settings file setup as specified in oracle documentation and encrypted my password and placed it in security settings file as well and my firewall is also off.

Can someone help me identify the source of this error.

Comment: It is unlikely that your command looked like the one you wrote. Revise `No plugin found for prefix 'DarchetypeRepository=https' ` and post entire cmd output including prompt.

Comment: You should rather update the question.

Comment: @Michael..here is the maven  i used command once again. please let me know is this will enable you find the source of this build failure:mvn archetype:generate
 -DarchetypeGroupId=com.oracle.weblogic.archetype
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=basicWebapp
 -DarchetypeVersion=12.1.3-0-0
 -DarchetypeRepository=https://maven.oracle.com

Comment: @Michael, I'm not working behind any firewall

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/tUHJHp3q
The firewall does not matter because your command line is incorrect.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your feedback. My command line text looks exactly as given by oracle in their documentation. You please take a look at it here:  https://redstack.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/otn-vts-oraclemavenrepository-labguide.pdf

Comment: I see, please add the full copy of cmd input:
`C:\> ...` I wan to see that.

Comment: Hi Michael, I was finally able to solve the problem by changing the entire maven command. Thanks

Comment: I told you it was the command!

Comment: Fixed formatting to make the question easier to read.